# Generating values from array to dropdown list

Tags: php, html

[image]

so I want to display only specific courses depending on the college of the student, which will come from a certain array instead of just listing all courses in one ...I think I kind of got the logic but the courses weren't displaying.

**Here's my code:**

```
<div class="student_reg">
    <form action = "registration.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="sn" placeholder="Student Number"><br>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname"><br>
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lastname"><br>
        <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age"><br>
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"><br>
        <input type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Confirm Password"><br><br>
        <textarea rows = "5" cols = "30" placeholder="Address" name = "address"></textarea><br><br>
        <label>Year Level</label>
        <select name = "yearLevel">
            <option>1st</option>
            <option>2nd</option>
            <option>3rd</option>
            <option>4th</option>
            <option>5th</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <select name = "college">
            <option value = "">College</option>
            <option>College of Engineering</option>
            <option>College of Fine Arts, Architecture and Design</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <?php
            $cengr = array("BSME", "BSECE", "BSCpE", "BSIE", "BSCE");
            $cfad = array("BSA", "BSID", "BFA Painting", "BFA Visual Com", " Multimedia Arts");
        ?>
        <select name = 'course'>
            <option value = "">Course</option>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['college'])){
                if($_POST['college'] == "College of Engineering"){
                    foreach($cengr as $course => $value){
                            echo "<option value =".$course.">".$value."</option>";
                    }
                }
                if($_POST['college'] == "College of Fine Arts, Architecture and Design"){
                    foreach($cfad as $course => $value){
                            echo "<option value =".$course.">".$value."</option>";
                    }
                }   
            }
        ?>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of compare college name you should compare  id value  of college  
 `if($_POST['college_id'] == 1)`

Comment: @JatinKaklotar What id? There is no `college_id` in the code.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($_POST['college']);` to see if the selection being posted correctly?

Comment: hi @FluffyKitten i tried just now, nothing happened

Comment: Well that's the problem - your page is not posting the values. Can you show us your form that you are using to post the values?

Comment: hi, i added a picture at the top

Comment: Thanks but we need to see the *code* you are using for your form. You have included the code for the `select` in your question, but a select is just an input field, it doesn't do anything by itself. If you are using `$_POST` then you must be using a form to submit your inputs?

Comment: yes @FluffyKitten the code for my form is there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217524/discussion-between-newbie-and-fluffykitten).